# same Columns go missing in non related DF in pandas when use Drop

Tags: pandas, drop

Very baffling to me.... when I drop cols 'Focus2','Score2','Focus3','Score3' from dfocus1, it drops the same cols in dfocus2

Why ?

```
'''

dfocus1=df
dfocus2=df
dfocus3=df

print('\nTable data',dfocus2.info(memory_usage='deep'))

dfocus1.drop(['Focus2','Score2','Focus3','Score3'], axis=1,inplace=True)

print('\nTable data',dfocus2.info(memory_usage='deep'))
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `dfocus1` and `dfocus2` are pointing to the same object(`df`).

Create a `copy` of `df` and then drop the columns:

```
dfocus1=df.copy()
dfocus2=df.copy()
```

Comment: Thank you kindly - new learning , wasted 2 hours drilling down to that line in the code